# Not Sending an email when Outlook is closed and opened

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I am making code changes to support Outlook. I am having problem sending email when I first open outlook i.e. it displays an email instead of sending it. But from the second time it automates email. And also .Send is not supported in my case. So I am using Sendkeys.

I have tried GetObject ,createObject but it doesn't solve my problem.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fully working VBScript to send the email (it works with closed and opened Outlook):

```vb
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objApp.CreateItem(0)
Set objRecip = objMail.Recipients.Add("Test User")
objRecip.Resolve
objMail.Subject = "Test"
objMail.Save
objMail.Send
objApp.Session.SendAndReceive(False)
```